# Storing NSObjects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How does one store a NSMutableArray of NSObjects to NSUserDefaults successfully?

I tried a few things and it doesnt seem to work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you storing actual NSObject instances or instances of a custom subclass?

Comment: I want to store an NSMutableArray of ALAssets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Note that a default’s value can be
>   only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray,
>   or NSDictionary.

As such, you cannot store a custom `NSObject`.

What you can do is create a method that turns your object into a dictionary with keys.

You also need a method that turs that dictionary into your object.

Once you have `NSObjects` that are property list objects you can just use:

```
//ObjectA could be a representation of your object using an NSDictionary.
NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:objectA, objectB, objectC, nil];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:objects forKey:@"StoredArray"];
[objects release];
//To save changes immediately
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: OP is not attempting to store a custom object. Question clearly states its a mutable array.

Comment: @Mark Adams: The questioner's comment on their question clearly states that they want to store an array of custom objects (ALAssets).

Comment: @Peter Hosey: This information was not available when I wrote the answer but I made sure it covered storing non property lists objects.
@Helium3 needs to write a method that turs ALAAsset into an object that can be stored and also write a method that converts a stored object back into ALAAsset. One way I can think of doing it is to store a reference to the ALAsset instead of the actual ALAAsset and retrieve it from the library when necesary, but it depends on the application.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation page:

> Values returned from `NSUserDefaults` are *immutable*, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for `"MyStringDefault"`, the string you later retrieve using `stringForKey:` will be immutable.

You can always turn an immutable array into a mutable one with:

```
NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:immutable];
```

As Zebs has already pointed out, you can only store plist-able objects into `NSUserDefaults` (NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSData, NSDate and NSNumber). The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDHAGB) also states:

> For `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, their contents must be property list objects.

So, if your array contains custom objects, you cannot put it in `NSUserDefaults`.